# Can't traverse the DOM with next

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following markup

```
<a class="list-group-item" href="#">
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-xs-10 shows-submenu'>
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">A title</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>

<div class='list-group-item hidden-group-item hide'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p class="list-group-item-text">
              Some text
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to remove the 'hide' class in the 'hidden-group-item' when I click the 'shows-submenu'. 
I was trying to do it with the following jQuery

```
$(function(){

    $('body').on('click', '.shows-submenu', function() {
      if ($(this).next('.hidden-group-item').hasClass('hide')) {
         $('.hidden-group-item').addClass('hide');
         $(this).next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
      }
      else {
         $(this).next('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');
      }
      $('.hidden-form-item').addClass('hide');
    });


});
```

but I can't make it work. The next() method seems to work only if the 'shows-submenu' class is added to the whole a tag but not in the col-xs-10 div where I want it to be.

Could you figure out why is this not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the following:

```
$(this).next('.hidden-group-item')
```

with

```
$(this).closest('a').next('.hidden-group-item')
```

and try again.

**Explanation:** `next()` get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.
And `hidden-group-item` is not the sibling in your html.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayank for your quick reply and brief explanation and works OK!

Comment: To learn DOM traverse take a look at : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing.asp

Answer (score 1):

`div.hidden-group-item` is not a sibling of `.shows-submenu` element thus [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will not work.

You can use [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up ancestor and then use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/)

```
 var hiddenDiv = $(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item');
```

You code can also be improved.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.shows-submenu', function() {
    var hiddenDiv = $(this).closest('a.list-group-item').next('.hidden-group-item');
    $('.hidden-form-item').not(this).addClass('hide');
    hiddenDiv.toggleClass('hide');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="list-group-item" href="#">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-xs-10 shows-submenu'>
      <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">A title</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<div class='list-group-item hidden-group-item hide'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <p class="list-group-item-text">
        Some text
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Satpal for the much better code and solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('body').on('click', '.shows-submenu', function() {
      if ($(this).closest(".list-group-item").next('.hidden-group-item').hasClass('hide')) ......
```

Answer (score 0):

next() method will only work in siblings.

use find() method instead like this.

$.find('.hidden-group-item').toggleClass('hide');